# Collapse sums of elements from multiple sequences into ordered list R

Tags: r, sequence

Let r = c(0,1,2) and s = c(0,5,10).  I want a function that can take r and s (eventually will take more than two sequences - I want to avoid loops if possible!), and return an ordered list of all unique combinations of sums of elements in r and s, i.e., return the following:

0,1,2,5,6,7,10,11,12

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar concept as @Didzis but using `outer` with `Reduce` instead:

```
as.vector(Reduce(function(x, y) outer(x, y, '+'), list(r, s, k)))
#  [1]  3  4  5  8  9 10 13 14 15  4  5  6  9 10 11 14 15 16  6  7  8 11 12 13 16 17 18
```

wrap it with a `sort` if necessary.

---

Small benchmarking:

```
w <- sample(50)
x <- sample(50)
y <- sample(50)
z <- sample(30)

# arun's 
system.time(t1 <- as.vector(Reduce(function(x, y) outer(x, y, '+'), list(w, x, y, z))))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.051   0.044   0.100 

# Didzis'
system.time(t2 <- rowSums(expand.grid(w, x, y, z)))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.167   0.308   1.579 

identical(as.numeric(t1), t2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: alternatively, you can move the `as.vector` part inside the function as: `function(x, y) as.vector(outer(x, y, '+'))` so that the result after each reduce operation is a vector (if you don't want to keep higher dimensional arrays until the end and coerce them to a vector. You may want to test it.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine functions `expand.grid()` and `rowSums()`. `expand.grid()` will make data frame of all combinations and `rowSums()` will calculate sums for those combinations.

```
r = c(0,1,2)
s = c(0,5,10)
rowSums(expand.grid(r,s))
[1]  0  1  2  5  6  7 10 11 12
```

With function `sort()` you can get values sorted.

```
r = c(0,1,2)
s = c(0,5,10)
k=c(3,4,6)
rowSums(expand.grid(r,s,k))
 [1]  3  4  5  8  9 10 13 14 15  4  5  6  9 10 11 14 15 16  6  7  8 11 12 13 16 17 18
sort(rowSums(expand.grid(r,s,k)))
 [1]  3  4  4  5  5  6  6  7  8  8  9  9 10 10 11 11 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 18
```

Comment: `expand.grid` gives a `data.frame` and `rowSums` coerces it to a `matrix` before summing. That's why I guess the run time is much different from using `outer`.